# [Gnosis-safe]What's the address of DefaultCallbackHandler in all Chain?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I'm trying to create my Safe proxy by compiling the contract myself, but I can't find DefaultCallbackHandler on each chain to implement the contract address.
Anyone have the address list?
I've tried looking at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/, but there doesn't seem to be a deployment address for this contract.

Answer (score 0):

In never versions the DefaultCallbackHandler was extended by the [CompatibilityFallbackHandler](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0-libs.0/contracts/handler/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.sol) and it is recommended to use that one. The addresses for this can be found [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/blob/v1.20.2/src/assets/v1.3.0/compatibility_fallback_handler.json)